# How to Calculate Difference Between 2 Timevals?

Tags: c, time, printing, printf, calculation

In my code I have:

```
struct timeval arrival_time, struct timeval pickup_time;

sprintf(buf, "Stat-Req-Dispatch:: %lu.%06d\r\n", (pickup_time.tv_sec - arrival_time.tv_sec),
        (pickup_time.tv_usec - arrival_time.tv_usec));
```

But I have noticed that this code isn't correct since sometimes the part which comes after `.` in printing might be negative.

I tried: `struct timeval dispatch_time = pickup_time-arrival_time;` but doesn't compile.

How can I properly print the difference between both times?

---

```
if (pickup_time.tv_usec < arrival_time.tv_usec)
{
    dispatch_time.tv_sec = pickup_time.tv_sec - arrival_time.tv_sec - 1;
    dispatch_time.tv_usec = pickup_time.tv_usec - arrival_time.tv_usec + 1000000;
} else
{
    dispatch_time.tv_sec = pickup_time.tv_sec - arrival_time.tv_sec;
    dispatch_time.tv_usec = pickup_time.tv_usec - arrival_time.tv_usec;
}

sprintf(buf, "%sStat-Req-Dispatch:: %lu.%06d\r\n", buf, dispatch_time.tv_sec, dispatch_time.tv_usec);
```

Comment: If `pickup_time.tv_usec` is less than `arrival_time.tv_usec`, add subtract one from the difference of the seconds and add one million to the difference of microseconds.

Comment: @EricPostpischil sorry But I didn't get you I am not that expert in units

Comment: @EricPostpischil is the code I wrote is what you meant?

Comment: Correcting typo (superfluous “add”): If `pickup_time.tv_usec` is less than `arrival_time.tv_usec`, subtract one from the difference of the seconds and add one million to the difference of microseconds.

Comment: It looks okay to me. You should test it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil are you sure 1 million? this adds much more https://gist.github.com/diabloneo/9619917

Comment: The code you have in the question has `usec` for microseconds. The code you link to in your comment has `nsec` for nanoseconds.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Linux+glibc, or a BSD OS, they give you [some macros](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timeradd.3.html) to manipulate `timeval`s, including one to calculate the difference between two times:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(void)
{
  struct timeval arrival_time = { .tv_sec = 100, .tv_usec = 50 },
    pickup_time = { .tv_sec = 150, .tv_usec = 0 },
    time_difference;
  timersub(&pickup_time, &arrival_time, &time_difference);
  printf("%ld seconds %ld useconds\n", (long)time_difference.tv_sec,
         (long)time_difference.tv_usec);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what about my solution is it correct?

Comment: @StewOr it looks like yours produces the same results as my version using `timersub()` with my test input, so... maybe? Would need to do more thorough testing to be sure.

Comment: Minor: for a _general purpose_ printing of `.tv_sec` which is type `time_t`, consider using the widest integer type rather than `long`.  `long` _may_ truncate.  e.g. `printf("%jd seconds\n", (intmax_t)time_difference.tv_sec);`.

Answer (score 0):

`timeval::tv_sec` is represented as seconds, and `timeval::tv_usec` is represented as microseconds.  Since you are just looking at the fields indivudally, `pickup_time` may have a higher `tv_sec` than `arrival_time`, but have a lesser `tv_usec` (ie, `arrival_time` could be 1 second 30 microseconds while `pickup_time` is 5 seconds 10 microseconds);

The GNU C documentation describes a `timeval_subtract()` function that accounts for this:

[21.3 Calculating Elapsed Time](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Calculating-Elapsed-Time.html)

> The GNU C Library does not provide any functions for computing the difference between two values of type struct timeval or struct timespec. Here is the recommended way to do this calculation by hand. It works even on some peculiar operating systems where the tv_sec member has an unsigned type.
>
> ```c
> /* Subtract the ‘struct timeval’ values X and Y,
>    storing the result in RESULT.
>    Return 1 if the difference is negative, otherwise 0. */
>
> int
> timeval_subtract (struct timeval *result, struct timeval *x, struct timeval *y)
> {
>   /* Perform the carry for the later subtraction by updating y. */
>   if (x->tv_usec < y->tv_usec) {
>     int nsec = (y->tv_usec - x->tv_usec) / 1000000 + 1;
>     y->tv_usec -= 1000000 * nsec;
>     y->tv_sec += nsec;
>   }
>   if (x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec > 1000000) {
>     int nsec = (x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec) / 1000000;
>     y->tv_usec += 1000000 * nsec;
>     y->tv_sec -= nsec;
>   }
>
>   /* Compute the time remaining to wait.
>      tv_usec is certainly positive. */
>   result->tv_sec = x->tv_sec - y->tv_sec;
>   result->tv_usec = x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec;
>
>   /* Return 1 if result is negative. */
>   return x->tv_sec < y->tv_sec;
> }
> ```

For example:

```c
struct timeval arrival_time, pickup_time, elapsed_time;
...
timeval_subtract(&elapsed_time, &pickup_time, &arrival_time);
sprintf(buf, "Stat-Req-Dispatch:: %lu.%06d\r\n", elapsed_time.tv_sec, elapsed_time.tv_usec);
```

Comment: `suseconds_t` is only guaranteed to hold values in the range `[-1, 1000000]`, so unless your timevals are less than a second, this is not portable. Even if `suseconds_t` is `long` on your architecture, you are still limited to small timevals. There is a reason why `struct timeval` stores two integers, and not store the time in a single `suseconds_t`

Comment: Good, now your program breaks in the year `7016474` rather than 2.jan.1970. Just remember that  `struct timeval` can store time-ponts (assumg 64-bit time_t) up til the year `292277026596`, so your implementation still have some "limitations". But this may not have any practical implications for most users.

Comment: @HAL9000 I removed my own example and instead use the example provided by the GNU C documentation.

Comment: So is this code correct now? plus why it's more complicated than the one I suggested

Comment: *The GNU C Library does not provide any functions for computing the difference between two values of type struct timeval ...* Except it does (see my answer). Strange. Maybe whoever wrote that just wasn't aware or it's old and never got updated.